# spray marshalling cats.data.Xor

Tags: scala, spray, scala-cats

I am writing REST api using spray and having some difficulties with json marshalling. My service returns cats.data.Xor[Failure, Success]. How can I return this data type from the REST endpoint? How to write response marshaller for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to call `toEither` on the value in your router, which lets the Spray-provided `Either` marshaller take over.

Another solution would be to provide your own marshaller (I've done this a couple of times myself):

```
import cats.data.Xor
import spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller

implicit def xorMarshaller[A, B](implicit
  ma: ToResponseMarshaller[A],
  mb: ToResponseMarshaller[B]
): ToResponseMarshaller[Xor[A, B]] =
  ToResponseMarshaller[Xor[A, B]] { (value, ctx) =>
    value match {
      case Xor.Left(a)  => ma(a, ctx)
      case Xor.Right(b) => mb(b, ctx)
    }
  }
```

This lets you avoid both the runtime cost (probably negligible) and syntactic cost (less negligible) of converting.

Note that Cats is removing `Xor` in favor of the standard library's `Either` in upcoming versions, though, so just going with `toEither` for now may be the most practical solution.